# Azure Parse Server Dashboard 404 Error

Tags: mongodb, azure, parse-server

I just set up my Parse Server on Azure using the template (published by Microsoft on the Marketplace). I already migrated my database onto mLab, so I went into my webapp, application settings, and updated my `DATABASE_URI` to my mLab database.

Is there anything else I need to do to set up the server and database? I have not gotten into the storage yet and have not touched any other options from the template.

When I go to my dashboard for the parse server, I click Parse Dashboard and the web pages eventually loads a 404 not found. My data has been migrated off of parse, so I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can you please provide more info? are you able to access your parse-server REST api's? can you share how you setup your parse-dashboard?

Comment: the parse dashboard was set up automatically when i created the template from the market place. I can test my "hello" cloud function using the REST API pointing to my Azure site so that is working.

Comment: from what i see in the docs you need to access the dashboard in the following way: https://<appId>:<masterKey>@<site>.azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard are you doing it like this? \

Comment: I assume that is the shortcut the template installed. I tried typing it in manually, it redirected me to https://<site>.azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard, and I eventually got a blank page saying: `Cannot GET /parse-d%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bashboard`